# Python too many subprocesses?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, subprocess

I'm trying to start a lot of python procees on a single machine.

Here is a code snippet:

```
fout = open(path, 'w')
p = subprocess.Popen((python_path,module_name),stdout=fout,bufsize=-1)
```

After about 100 processes I'm getting the error below:

[image]

Running on win 10 64 bit, Python 3.5. Any Idea what that might be? Already tried to split the start (so start from two scripts) as well as sleep command. After a certain number of processes, the error shows up. Any Idea what that might be? Thanks a lot for any hint!

PS:
Some background. Each process opens database connections as well as does some requests using the requests package. Then some calculations are done using numpy, scipy etc.

PPS: Just discover this error message:
dll load failed the paging file is too small for this operation to complete python (when calling scipy)

Answer (score -1):

Issues solved through  reinstalling numpy and scipy + installing mkl.

Strange about this error was that it only appeared after a certain number of processes. Would love to hear if anybody knows why this happened!

Comment: Don't think that this is a solution.

Comment: For me it was at least for me. Numpy was compiled without mkl and caused this error in my case.